# How to make threads wait for ReentrantLock to be released?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

If a thread has acquired a lock, I want other threads to skip trying to acquire the lock and simply wait for the lock to be released before continuing execution. I do NOT want the other threads to acquire the lock once it is released.

I've been reading up on the subject, but am still confused.

See the following generalized code snippet below:

```
private final ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();

public void aCoolMethod(){
    if (reentrantLock.tryLock() == true){
        try {
            doSomething();
        } finally {
            reentrantLock.unlock();
        }
    } else {
        // have threads wait until reentrantLock is unlocked
    }
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

How can I have threads that enter my else block wait for reentrant lock to be unlocked before continuing execution?

Comment: why not call `isLocked` ?

Comment: If you want to "wait" (block) until the lock is available, you can use `lock()` instead of `tryLock()`. If you just want to check, you can call `isLocked()`.

Comment: You can try `CountDownLatch`

Comment: @Thilo If I use lock() instead of tryLock(), the blocked thread will acquire the lock once it is released. I want it to go to my else block and wait for the lock to be unlocked. Is your idea to use a while loop? While (reentrantLock.isLocked()) { // do nothing } ?

Comment: The question is unclear. Why do you want to wait for the lock to be unlocked and then NOT lock it again? Why wait at all then? I suppose you could do `if (!tryLock()){ lock(); unlock(); // lock to wait until is free, but then immediately unlock, don't actually do anything }`

Comment: A [Phaser](https://www.baeldung.com/java-phaser) might work

Comment: @Thilo the method, aCoolMethod(), will be called when a certain exception is thrown. Other threads may run into the same exception and will enter the same method block. The first thread will fix the issue and I need the other threads to wait for the first thread to finish fixing the issue. I thought a lock would be a good idea for this, since I don't know how many threads will call the method at a given time. I need all threads but the first to wait. I believe if I place the while loop I mentioned (in my previous comment) inside the else block in example code, it will accomplish what I want.

Comment: It sounds like you can just `lock` and once you get the lock, you check whether the fix has been applied (have a flag or timestamp) and if not, you do the fixup (and set the flag, releasing the lock only afterwards). Checking the flag while you are holding the lock makes sure that there will be no race-conditions.

Comment: IMO, you should not use a `Lock` instance for any other purpose except to grant access to shared variables. If your goal is to synchronize the actions of two or more threads, then you should use some other object (e.g., a `CyclicBarrier`, or a `Semaphore`, or whatever works) so that your intent will be more obvious to other programmers who may need to read your code.

Comment: @Thilo You can check a flag w/o locking if you recheck after locking and ensure visibility of the "fix" with a synchronize-with relation. Or use the simple approach as the code is only used for exceptions and prob. not efficiency critical.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Posting the solution I ended up using in case anyone else has a similar issue. I chose to use wait-notify strategy. While the other answers were helpful, this works well for my situation and is simple enough.

```
private final ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();

public void aCoolMethod(){
    if (reentrantLock.tryLock()){
        try {
            doSomething();
        } finally {
            reentrantLock.unlock();
            synchronized (reentrantLock) {
                reentrantLock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    } else {
        // have threads wait until reentrantLock is unlocked
        synchronized (reentrantLock) {
            while(reentrantLock.isLocked()) {
                try {
                    reentrantLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    doSomethingElse();
}
```

**Edit:** Posting test class so others can test this solution. Simply copy/paste and run it. See below:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.lang.Thread;

public class LockTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();

        Thread thread0 = new Thread () {
            public void run () {
                testClass.testLock();
            }
        };
        Thread thread1 = new Thread () {
            public void run () {
                testClass.testLock();
            }
        };
        Thread thread2 = new Thread () {
            public void run () {
                testClass.testLock();
            }
        };

        thread0.start();
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

    }

    public static class TestClass{
        ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();

        public void testLock(){
            if (reentrantLock.tryLock()) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Locking");
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " will sleep");
                    Thread.sleep(8000);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has woken up from sleep!!");
                } catch (InterruptedException i) {
                    System.out.println("Interrupted during sleep");
                } finally {
                    System.out.println("Unlocking");
                    reentrantLock.unlock();
                    System.out.println("Notifying");
                    synchronized (reentrantLock) {
                        reentrantLock.notifyAll();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                synchronized (reentrantLock) {
                    while(reentrantLock.isLocked()) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " will wait");
                            reentrantLock.wait();
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has woken up from wait!!");
                        } catch (InterruptedException i) {
                            System.out.println("Interrupted during wait");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has reached the end.");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: There's still a race condition that allows more than one thread to call `doSomething()`. Also, your threads might deadlock. The thread that calls `doSomething()` can never get inside the `synchronized` block to call `reentrantLock.notifyAll()` if another thread is paused on `reentrantLock.wait()`.

Comment: I think you are wrong, but I could also be wrong hehe. Can you explain more? Reentrantlock will only allow 1 thread to enter the critical section at a time, so there will be no race condition since only 1 thread will be able to reach doSomething() at a time. Also, the thread that holds the lock is the one trying to enter the synchronized block to call notifyAll(), so it will have no issue entering that section. I wrote some simple code to test this scenario and it works as intended.

Comment: @Eric I've posted my test class. Please run it and you will see how it works. I don't think there is any race condition or issue with notifying other threads, but again I could be wrong. Appreciate the feedback either way!

Comment: Using synchronized for this is horrible, -1. if you need to use notify-like functionality with Locks it would be a lot better to check out Condition and use the analogous signal/await functionality.

Comment: It could very well happen that by the time one thread has exited the critical section, another thread can acquire the lock and run `doSomething()`again. In fact, with your test code, I confirmed it. The rest of your code is ugly but it works. When a thread calls `reentrantLock.wait()`, it gives up the monitor, allowing the other thread to enter the `synchronized` block to call `reentrantLock.notifyAll()`. As @NathanHughes says, using `synchronized` in this example is just ugly, it's even uglier using using `reentrantLock` as the monitor. Use `ReentrantLock`'s `Condition` for signal/wait.

Answer (score 2):

As Thilo mentioned, a better way to solve your problem is to have a critical section that contains a flag that the threads first check. If the flag hasn't been set, fix your issue and set the flag before exiting the critical section. If the flag has been set, you know another thread got there first and fixed the problem, so just exit the critical section.

```
private final ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();
private boolean fixed = false;

public void aCoolMethod(){
    try {
        reentrantLock.lock();

        if (!fixed) {
            doSomething();
        }
    } finally {
        fixed = true;
        reentrantLock.unlock();
    }

    doSomethingElse();
}
```

Alternatively, without locks, you can use a consensus object to determine which thread runs `doSomething()`:

```
private final AtomicBoolean turn = new AtomicBoolean(true);
private volatile boolean done = false;

public void aCoolMethod(){
    if (turn.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
        doSomething();
        done = true;
    } else {
        while (!done) {
          // spin or wait for condition
        }
        doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Note that with this approach, you don't even need an explicit `ReentrantLock`; you can just use `synchronized` on an arbitrary shared object.

Comment: Would creating this new boolean be better than simply using reentrantLock.isLocked() in the else block from the code example I posted in the question? Like so: while (reentrantLock.isLocked()) { // do nothing }. If I use this boolean as you suggested, won't every thread have to acquire the lock, since we will have basically created a FIFO queue filled with threads. Each thread will have to wait for the thread in front of it to finish checking that boolean before it can acquire the lock and check the boolean itself.

Comment: It depends on what your requirements are. The problem with the code you provided is that it is vulnerable due to a race condition. Once the thread that calls `doSomething()` exits the critical section, any other thread is free to enter and call `doSomething()` again. There are other ways to solve this without using locks at all, such as using a wait-free consensus object like test-and-set or compare-and-exchange. In Java, that would mean using `AtomicBoolean::compareAndSet` to determine which thread gets to run `doSomething()`.

Comment: Why not a semaphore?

Comment: @curiousguy, I suppose it would work? Please share your idea. :)